# Laravel gives 404 error for root (/) url but other urls work fine

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 6 and for some reason when using Route::get('/','HomeController@Index') I get 404 not found error but any other urls like Route::get('/home','HomeController@Index') works just fine.

Comment: run php artisan route:list , what is the output?

Comment: did you check your Controller name and class name are same or not?

Comment: Yes they're same